# Ocultar tabla al hacer clic

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showAndHide() {
    $('#tools_info').toggle(1700);
    return false;
  } 
<script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showAndHideTableGood() {
    if (this.id == "Btn_tgood") {
      $('#tgood').show().toggle("slow");
      $('#tbad').hide().toggle("slow");
    } else {
      $('#tgood').toggle("slow");
      return false;
    }
  } 
<script>
```

```css
#tgood {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#tbad {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<button id="Btn_fch" onclick="showAndHide();" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">FCH </button>

<div id="tools_info" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" style="width: 450px">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>&nbsp Tools information</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button id="Btn_tgood" class="btn-link" type="button" onclick="showAndHideTableGood();">Good condition</button>
        <button class="btn-link" type="button" onclick="showAndHideTableBad();">Bad condition</button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <table id="tgood">
        <tr style="text-align: center">
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="501" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="502" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="503" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="504" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button11" runat="server" Text="505" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="506" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table id="tbad">
        <tr style="text-align: center">
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="601" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="602" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" Text="603" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align: center">
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button13" runat="server" Text="604" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button14" runat="server" Text="605" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button15" runat="server" Text="606" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm outline" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tengo una función, la cual al darle clic a un botón, esta se activa y muestra una tabla, pero al querer cerrar dicha tabla volviendo a dar clic al botón, esta tabla no se oculta, solo hace el efecto de volver a mostrarse.

este es el código de mi función:

```
<script>
    function showAndHideTableGood() {
        if (this.id == "Btn_tgood") {
            $('#tgood').toggle("slow");
        } else {
            $('#tbad').show().toggle("slow");
            $('#tgood').hide().toggle("slow");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Puedes hacer un ejemplo añadiendo el HTML y creando un snippet de codigo para probar ?

Comment: te sobran el show y el hide del else, toggle ya hace ese trabajo, lo que estás haciendo es 2 veces el mismo trabajo, por eso ves el efecto(del toggle("slow"))

Comment: el codigo tiene errores, al correrlo en stackoverflow `{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 96,
  "colno": 9
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es tu funcion acutal

```
  function showAndHideTableGood() {
    if (this.id == "Btn_tgood") {
      $('#tgood').show().toggle("slow");
      $('#tbad').hide().toggle("slow");
    } else {
      $('#tgood').toggle("slow");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Te recomiendo cambiarla por la siguiente:

```
fucntion showAndHideTableGood(){
   if(('#tgood').is(':visible')){  
     $('#tgood').hide();
     $('#tbad').hide();
   }else{
      $('#tgood').show();
     $('#tbad').show();
   }
}
```

la proiedad visible busca el css `display:block`, la funcion `.hide()` y `.show()` agregar el siguiente codigo al bloque `HTML`:

```
.show() sytle="display:block;"
.hide() style="display:none;"
```

Si tienes alguna duda comenta.

Suerte.

**Actualizacion**

Esto para evitar algun runtimeException y tambien ayudaria saber que version de JQuery estas utilizando.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    fucntion showAndHideTableGood(){
       if(('#tgood').is(':visible')){  
         $('#tgood').hide();
         $('#tbad').hide();
       }else{
          $('#tgood').show();
         $('#tbad').show();
       }
    }
});
```

**Actualizacion 2**
Debe ser un conflicto con JQuery, el sitema en el que yo utilice `.is()` esta en la version 3.1 pero no dice que se deprecio en la documentacion del 3.2

```
<script>
$m=jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $m(document).ready(function () {
        fucntion showAndHideTableGood(){
   if(('#tgood').is(':visible')){  
     $('#tgood').hide();
     $('#tbad').hide();
   }else{
      $('#tgood').show();
     $('#tbad').show();
   }
}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'is'` me señala ese error

Comment: Eso pasa por que se esta ejecutando esta fraccion de codigo antes de cargar todo el contenido de la pagina, metelo dentro de $(document).ready();
Tambien puede ser tu version de JQuery, cual estas usando?

Comment: lo coloque de esta manera `<script>
        $(document).ready(); {
            function showAndHideTableGood() {
                if (('#tgood').is(':visible')) {
                    $('#tgood').hide();
                    $('#tbad').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#tgood').show();
                    $('#tbad').show();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>` y me sigue arrojando el error

Comment: Actualice la respuesta

Comment: me ganaste, de igual manera lo puse como me acabas de indicar e igualmente me arroja el error

Comment: estoy usando estas version de jquery `<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>...
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>` instale las que me da visualstudio en el `NuGet package`

Comment: Ahi esta el problema, esas versiones de jquery no soportan la function .is()
Actualiza tu version. La documentacion esta mucho mas amplia y hay funciones que se depreciaron.

Comment: de hecho lo acabo de actualizar y ya funciono, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Te sobran el `show/hide` ya que está hecho con el `toggle()`

```
<script>
    function showAndHideTableGood() {
        if (this.id == "Btn_tgood") {
            $('#tgood').toggle("slow");
        } else {
            $('#tbad').toggle("slow");
            $('#tgood').toggle("slow");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: el show y el hide lo puse en caso de que diera clic al otro boton (el cual tambien muestra otra tabla oculta)

Comment: me refiero a que si haces       `$('#tgood').show().toggle("slow");` estás haciendo que `$('#good')` pase a `display: block` con el `show()` pero luego con el `toggle()` le estás volviendo a cambiar a `display: none` y lo mismo con el otro y al llevar el slow ves como se vuelve a ocultar lentamente.

Comment: quise poner una condicion en el mismo if con una variable para que al hacer un Segundo clic se ocultara la tabla nuevamente pero no funciono la sentensia fue algo asi: `<script>
        function showAndHideTableGood() {
            var x = clic;
            if (this.id == "Btn_tgood" && x == 1) {
                $('#tgood').toggle("slow");
                x + 1;
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#tbad').show().toggle("slow");
                $('#tgood').hide().toggle("slow");
            }
        }
    </script>`

Comment: esto?? https://jsfiddle.net/f6o0dqxf/3/

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo aquí hecho en jquery, solo cambia las etiquetas y ya esta

```
<button id="btn1">Ver/Ocultar</button>
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
    <img src="ejem.png" alt=""/>
    <p>Imagen de una carita</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("#div1").slideToggle(3000);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Añadiéndole el "toggle" te funcionará perfectamente.